# .htaccess rewriteRule help

Tags: php, javascript, html, .htaccess, browser

I have a link in my index.html:

```
  href="my_page.php?cat=14&p=1";
```

Now, how can I rewrite this so that it looks like this:

```
 /my_page/14/1
```

I have this so far, but I don't know how to add the ending '/1' to this:

```
  RewriteRule ^kategori/([0-9_]+)$ browse_cat.php?cat_gr=$1 [NC]
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't completely understand what you're trying to do. Do you want the *browser* address bar to show `/my_page/14/1` and the *server* to see `/my_page.php?cat=14&p=1` (which would make sense) or the other way around?

Comment: I am trying to rewrite a URL... Exactly, thats what I want... You said it.

Comment: You'll need to fix the links in your `index.html`, then, once you get the rewrite rule fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have no apache installed here at home, but this should do the trick.

```
  RewriteRule ^kategori/([0-9_]+)(?:/(0-9]+))?$ browse_cat.php?cat_gr=$1&p=$2 [NC]
```

(?: ...)? makes the second part optional. So /kategori/14 as well as /kategori/14/1 should work.

If not, you'll need two rules

```
  RewriteRule ^kategori/([0-9_]+)$ browse_cat.php?cat_gr=$1 [NC]
  RewriteRule ^kategori/([0-9_]+)(?:/(0-9]+))?$ browse_cat.php?cat_gr=$1&p=$2 [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ReWriteCond {%REQUEST_URI} ^/my_page/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)
ReWriteRule .* /my_page.php?cat=%1&p=%2 [NC,L]
```

This would only work if both cat and p at a minimum are specified.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re actually using URLs like `/my_page.php?cat=14&p=1` and want them to be “displayed” as `/my_page/14/1`, you will need two rules: One to redirect `/my_page.php?cat=14&p=1` externally to `/my_page/14/1` and one to rewrite `/my_page/14/1` internally to `/my_page.php?cat=14&p=1`.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /my_page\.php\?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=([0-9]+)&p=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^my_page\.php$ /my_page/%1/%2 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^my_page/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ my_page.php?cat=$1&p=$2 [L]
```

Note that this rule does only work with this specific URL (number and order or parameters). A more general rule will get more complex; using a higher level language like PHP is probably easier in this case.

Furthermore, it would be better if you already use the “right” URL in your HTML documents rather than redirecting/rewriting every request twice.